# Getting and updating all users Asp.net Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an Asp.Net Core 1.1 + Identity web application. I need a function that would get all Identity users, perform some actions with their properties and then update the DB with new data. This is the class I have written:

```
public class WeightCalc
{
    private UserManager<User> um;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public WeightCalc(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
       um = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(_context), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public async void Calculate()
    {
        var users = um.Users;
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            var level = _context.Multipliers.SingleOrDefault(p => (p.Lower < user.rating) && (p.Higher > user.rating)); 
            user.Weight = level.Mul; 
           var result = await um.UpdateAsync(user);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I am calling this function for debug purposes:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async void rateupdate() 
    {            
        WeightCalc test = new WeightCalc(_context);
        test.Calculate();

    }
```

Apparently, it has no effect on the data in DB. Where did I go wrong? I have some questions about all nulls in the usermanager, but I do believe I saw a post on SO where it was said that is acceptable

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to help you narrow it down? e.g. Does the `foreach` loop execute at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `_context.saveChanges();` after  `var result = await um.UpdateAsync(user);`?

Comment: Shame on me, I totally missed it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
var users = _context.Users.ToList();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    var level = _context.Multipliers.SingleOrDefault(p => (p.Lower < user.rating) && (p.Higher > user.rating)); 
    user.Weight = level.Mul; 
}

_context.Users.UpdateRange(users);
_context.SaveChanges();
```